# Question about a matrix, need attempt verification

Tags: matrices

I am supposed to provide a matrix that has the following properties:

- non-zero
- symmetric
- upper triangular
- dimension $4\times 4$

Here's is my attempt, can someone verify if this is correct?

\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Correct $\color{green} \checkmark$.  You've done just fine, Sarah!  That's a very valid matrix with all the properties you mentioned. Kudos!  Was there any reason you were uncertain?

Comment: @amWhy I was just confused about the non-zero requirement. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Non-zero simply means not a 4 by 4 matrix filled with only zeros.  The identity matrix you show is a great example to appeal to in such a case.  Anyway, glad if I helped.

Comment: It seems that you are confused with the meaning of "non-zero" matrices. A zero matrix is an matrix consisting of all 0s. Any matrix different from a zero matrix is "non-zero".

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. Any non-zero diagonal matrix will do.